# Unable to control Javascript popup in Firefox browser in Ruby Watir

Tags: javascript, ruby, watir

In a page, when I click on a certain button, I get a javascript popup with 'Ok' and 'Cancel' buttons. I want to click 'Ok' button in that popup using Ruby Watir script. So I use the following code. I get the FAIL message since javascript popup comes and goes out within fraction of a second in Firefox browser. So to check whether the script catches the alert, I did print `p browser.alert.present?` and I get that as false. How to handle such a issue?

```
if (certain_button_click)
    p browser.alert.present? #I get this as 'false'

    browser.wait_until(30) {
        browser.alert.present?
    } rescue nil 

    p browser.alert.present? #I get this as 'false'      

    if browser.alert.present?
        browser.alert.ok
        message = 'Click Ok - PASS'
    else
        message = 'Click Ok - FAIL'
    end
end
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Ashwin

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I can't tell what you are trying to accomplish here, but I see what your code is doing.

Selenium raises an `UnhandledAlertError` whenever an alert is present, but a non-alert related action is taken with the driver. What your code is doing is rescuing that exception (well, all exceptions, which you should avoid doing when you know which exception you want to avoid). Firefox has [different behavior](https://github.com/watir/watir/issues/280#issuecomment-59603337) than Chrome in this respect in that it also closes the alert when it raises the exception. So your code is doing exactly what you are telling it to do.

if you use Watir 6.0 you don't have to specify the waits any longer. If you only want to dismiss an alert when it shows up, this code will automatically wait for the alert to show up and click ok when it does. If the alert never shows up it will give a timeout error.

```
element_causing_alert.click
browser.alert.ok
```

If you are trying to test that the alert shows up, then you can use this code:

```
begin
  browser.alert.ok
  true
rescue Watir::Wait::TimeoutError
  false
end
```

Or if you want to specify the time to wait before timing out:

```
begin
  browser.alert.wait_until(timeout: 5, &:present?).ok
  true
rescue Watir::Wait::TimeoutError
  false
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate idea. You can use `execute_script` in the browser which 'stubs out' the alert call to set a global variable. Then another `execute_script` which checks that the variable was set.

Example:

```
def stub_alert
  script = <<-JS
    window.alert = function(){ window.alerted = true }
  JS
  browser.execute_script stub_alert
end

def check_for_alert
  script = <<-JS
    return window.alerted == true
  JS
  browser.execute_script stub_alert
end
```

Watir uses selenium under the hood, and there's some tricky things about working with alerts. I've experienced the situation where Selenium's reference to the alert disappeared if I ran any javascript before handling the alert.

Comment: I described the reason for the behavior you witnessed in my answer. What were you trying to do with the alert present that couldn't be done through the Selenium API? In general I recommend against using javascript workarounds unless it is an absolute last resort.

Comment: If one really needed their test case to interact with the alert, such as entering text, then of course the selenium api is the way to go. But just to say "was an alert raised?" is simpler and removes the need to know the details of alert handling.

Comment: In Watir there is `browser.alert.present?` that gives you that functionality. And we'll just have to agree to disagree on the simplicity of your javascript code. ;-)

Comment: @titusfortner Selenium's alert handling system feels to me like it still has room for improvement. For example, how you can't differentiate between alerts/confirms/prompts. Also, how `UnhandledAlertError` closes the alert, which may be unintende. If it wasn't for this stuff I wouldn't be as keen to recommend stubbing it out

Comment: Selenium 4 with W3C should make it more standardized between browsers (https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#user-prompts). Note that geckodriver has a bug right now where it never throws that error. Also, Firefox & IE both allow for auto-dismissal of alerts by setting a capability (UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR), this will also be supported in W3C. If you consider it important to be able to distinguish between the different types of alerts, you should raise an issue with W3C - https://github.com/w3c/webdriver